# Google Analytics Goal Funnel Help - Shows Drops Off When They Are Not

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have a goal set up in GA for purchases. I have it set to a destination goal that uses my thank you screen. However, my funnel is not working correctly. It shows that a major chunk of my users are exiting to a specific URL but that url is the next step in the funnel. Why does it show them leaving the funnel and not counting them as a purchaser when they should be?

Thanks

I've attached a screenshot of the funnel.

The "/members/index.php?s=155" is the "Vacant Land Payment" screen.
[screenshot of GA funnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TcpZ.jpg)

Goal Setup [StepOne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TcpZ.jpg)

Goal Description[StepTwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udxgw.jpg)

Goal Details[StepThree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNbQ9.jpg)

Side By Side[Sidebyside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXaSG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This happens for the logics with which that type of funnel shows the data: the previous step cannot have a value lower than the next so if it is lower it brings it back to the minimum possible.

You can find more information on how that funnel works, with a practical example, here:

https://www.analyticstraps.com/quando-la-visualizzazione-canalizzazione-mente/

Comment: When you say the value is lower than the next, are you meaning that "155" and "156"? So to fix it I could change the URL of the 155 to 157? Or do you recommend a different way of changing it. Like having the steps always be text and then only the thank you page be a number?

Comment: Also, thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: I mean the value of sessions shown in the steps of the funnel. Have you read the article?

Comment: Yes, I understand some of it but I don't completely know what to do to fix it.

Comment: Where does the problem arise? Could be user sessions that aren't actually moving forward, right?

Comment: I don't understand why the funnel is showing there was 42 users who exited to page "...=155" from step 2,  when the next step (Vacant Land Payment) is the "...=155"

Comment: If you added or changed an existing funnel the Funnel Visualization report only reflects data going forward and doesn't show retroactive data. Try to see last days.